# Adding hash keys

Tags: perl

I am adding data to a hash using an incrementing numeric key starting at 0. The key/value is fine. When I add the second one, the first key/value pair points back to the second. Each addition after that replaces the value of the second key and then points back to it. The `Dumper` output would be something like this.

```
$VAR1 = { '0' => { ... } };
```

After the first key/value is added. After the second one is added I get

```
$VAR1= { '1' => { ... }, '0' => $VAR1->{'1} };
```

After the third key/value is added, it looks like this.

```
$VAR1 = { '1' => { ... }, '0' => $VAR1->{'1'}, '2' => $VAR1->{'1'} };
```

My question is why is it doing this? I want each key/value to show up in the hash. When I iterate through the hash I get the same data for every key/value. How do I get rid of the reference pointers to the second added key?

Comment: Maybe you should provide the code that causes the problem.

Comment: If you don't show us how you're adding the items, how on earth are we supposed to help?

Comment: What do you mean by "explain properly"? What other explanation do you need?

Comment: [A short self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org) program demonstrating the problem would be nice.

Comment: $index = 0; $hash1{ $index } = \%hash2; $index++;

Comment: As you can see, I'm not used to posting on here. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you're telling it to do...what do you WANT the hash to look like

Comment: That's not really a self-contained example (it doesn't demonstrate the problem on its own), but thanks, I think I can guess what your problem is now.  Let me just type up an answer...

Comment: $VAR1=>{ '0' => 'value0', '1' => 'value1', '2' => 'value2' };

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the value of every element to a reference to the same hash. Data::Dumper is merely reflecting that.

If you're using Data::Dumper as a serializing tool (yuck!), then you should set `$Data::Dumper::Purity` to `1` to get something `eval` can process.

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my %h2 = (a=>5,b=>6,c=>7);

my %h;
$h{0} = \%h2;
$h{1} = \%h2;
$h{2} = \%h2;

print("$h{0}{c} $h{2}{c}\n");
$h{0}{c} = 9;
print("$h{0}{c} $h{2}{c}\n");

{
   local $Data::Dumper::Purity = 1;
   print(Dumper(\%h));
}
```

Output:

```
7 7
9 9
$VAR1 = {
          '0' => {
                   'c' => 9,
                   'a' => 5,
                   'b' => 6
                 },
          '1' => {},
          '2' => {}
        };
$VAR1->{'0'} = $VAR1->{'1'};
$VAR1->{'2'} = $VAR1->{'1'};
```

---

If, on the other hand, you didn't mean to use store references to different hashes, you could use

```
# Shallow copies
$h{0} = { %h2 };  # { ... }   means   do { my %anon = ( ... ); \%anon }
$h{1} = { %h2 };
$h{2} = { %h2 };
```

or

```
# Deep copies
use Storable qw( dclone );
$h{0} = dclone(\%h2);
$h{1} = dclone(\%h2);
$h{2} = dclone(\%h2);
```

Output:

```
7 7
9 7
$VAR1 = {
          '0' => {
                   'a' => 5,
                   'b' => 6,
                   'c' => 9
                 },
          '1' => {
                   'a' => 5,
                   'b' => 6,
                   'c' => 7
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'a' => 5,
                   'b' => 6,
                   'c' => 7
                 }
        };
```

Comment: You are correct. I didn't mean to use store references. Your second example is exactly what I want. I have implemented your suggestion and it works like a charm. I have also learned more about perl references. Thank you.

Comment: Hashes (and arrays) can only contains scalars. You have to store references since you can't store a hash in a hash. The problem is that were storing references to one hash rather than references to different hashes.

Comment: copies (shallow, or deep if needed) will fix the problem, but usually the better fix is changing code like `my %h; for/while ... { ... \%h ... } ` to `for/while ... { my %h; ... \%h ... }` (so each iteration is a new hash in the first place)  (update: which I now see Ilmari Karonen's answer says)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted the actual code you're using to build the hash, but I assume it looks something like this:

```
foreach my $i (1 .. 3) {
    %hash2 = (number => $i, foo => "bar", baz => "whatever");
    $hash1{$i} = \%hash2;
}
```

(Actually, I'll guess that, in your actual code, you're probably reading data from a file in a `while (<>)` loop and assigning values to `%hash2` based on it, but the `foreach` loop will do for demonstration purposes.)

If you run the code above and dump the resulting `%hash1` using Data::Dumper, you'll get the output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'baz' => 'whatever',
                   'number' => 3,
                   'foo' => 'bar'
                 },
          '3' => $VAR1->{'1'},
          '2' => $VAR1->{'1'}
        };
```

Why does it look like that?  Well, it's because the values in `%hash1` are all references pointing to the *same* hash, namely `%hash2`.  When you assign new values to `%hash2` in your loop, those values will overwrite the old values in `%hash2`, but it will still be the same hash.  Data::Dumper is just highlighting that fact.

So, how can you fix it?  Well, there are (at least) two ways.  One way is to replace `\%hash2`, which gives a reference to `%hash2`, with `{ %hash2 }`, which *copies* the contents of `%hash2` into a new anonymous hash and returns a reference to that:

```
foreach my $i (1 .. 3) {
    %hash2 = (number => $i, foo => "bar", baz => "whatever");
    $hash1{$i} = { %hash2 };
}
```

The other (IMO preferable) way is to declare `%hash2` as a (lexically scoped) local variable within the loop using `my`:

```
foreach my $i (1 .. 3) {
    my %hash2 = (number => $i, foo => "bar", baz => "whatever");
    $hash1{$i} = \%hash2;
}
```

This way, each iteration of the loop will create a *new*, different hash named `%hash2`, while the hashes created on previous iterations will continue to exist (since they're referenced from `%hash1`) independently.

By the way, you wouldn't have had this problem in the first place if you'd followed standard Perl best practices, specifically:

- Always `use strict;` (and `use warnings;`).  This would've forced you to declare `%hash2` with `my` (although it wouldn't have forced you to do so *inside* the loop).
- Always declare local variables in the smallest possible scope.  In this case, since `%hash2` is only used within the loop, you should've declared it inside the loop, like above.

Following these best practices, the example code above would look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my %hash1;
foreach my $i (1 .. 3) {
    my %hash2 = (number => $i, foo => "bar", baz => "whatever");
    $hash1{$i} = \%hash2;
}

print Dumper(\%hash1);
```

which, as expected, will print:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'baz' => 'whatever',
                   'number' => 1,
                   'foo' => 'bar'
                 },
          '3' => {
                   'baz' => 'whatever',
                   'number' => 3,
                   'foo' => 'bar'
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'baz' => 'whatever',
                   'number' => 2,
                   'foo' => 'bar'
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what the problem is when you don't post the code or the actual results of Data::Dumper.

There is one thing you should know about Data::Dumper: When you dump an array or (especially) a hash, you should dump a reference to it. Otherwise, Data::Dumper will treat it like a series of variables. Also notice that hashes ***do not*** remain in the order you create them. I've enclosed an example below. Make sure that your issue isn't related to a confusing Data::Dumper output.

Another question: If you're keying your hash by sequential keys, would you be better off with an array?

If you can, please edit your question to post your code and the ACTUAL results.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = qw(one two three four five);

my %hash = (one => 1, two => 2, three => 3, four => 4);

say "Dumped Array: " . Dumper @array;
say "Dumped Hash: " . Dumper %hash;
say "Dumped Array Reference: " . Dumper \@array;
say "Dumped Hash Reference: " . Dumper \%hash;
```

The output:

```
Dumped Array: $VAR1 = 'one';
$VAR2 = 'two';
$VAR3 = 'three';
$VAR4 = 'four';
$VAR5 = 'five';

Dumped Hash: $VAR1 = 'three';
$VAR2 = 3;
$VAR3 = 'one';
$VAR4 = 1;
$VAR5 = 'two';
$VAR6 = 2;
$VAR7 = 'four';
$VAR8 = 4;

Dumped Array Reference: $VAR1 = [
          'one',
          'two',
          'three',
          'four',
          'five'
        ];

Dumped Hash Reference: $VAR1 = {
          'three' => 3,
          'one' => 1,
          'two' => 2,
          'four' => 4
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is doing this is you are giving it the same reference to the same hash.
Presumably in a loop construct.

Here is a simple program which has this behaviour.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# always use the above two lines until you
# understand completely why they are recommended

use Data::Printer;

my %hash;
my %inner; # <-- wrong place to put it

for my $index (0..5){
  $inner{int rand} = $index; # <- doesn't matter

  $hash{$index} = \%inner;
}

p %hash;
```

To fix it just make sure that you are creating a fresh hash reference every time through the loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my %hash;

for my $index (0..5){
  my %inner; # <-- place the declaration here instead

  $inner{int rand} = $index; # <- doesn't matter

  $hash{$index} = \%inner;
}

p %hash;
```

---

If you are only going to use numbers for your indexes, and they are monotonically increasing starting from 0, then I would recommend using an array.
An array would be faster and more memory efficient.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my @array; # <--

for my $index (0..5){
  my %inner;
  $inner{int rand} = $index;

  $array[$index] = \%inner; # <--
}

p @array;
```